# Datepicker calendar always show

Tags: magento2.3, datepicker, calendar, customer-registration, input

I need to always show calendar popup in div below input with datepicker. 
There is my code

```
<div class="field date">
            <input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" value="" class="datepicker">
            <script>
                require(["jquery", "mage/calendar"], function($){
                    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                        showMonthAfterYear: false,
                        dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy',
                        changeMonth: false,
                        changeYear: false,
                        firstDay: 0,
                        showsTime: false,
                        hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
                        minDate: new Date(),
                        yearRange: '2020:2025',
                    })
                });
            </script>
        </div>
```

How can i do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign datepicker  to a `<div>` instead of an input box.

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```